# Browser error during django + SSL connection with local server

Tags: django, facebook, google-chrome, ssl

I have a problem during adding facebook login button to my website at localhost.

I've already add mysite.com to hosts file and installed django-extensions, werkzeug, pyOpenSSL. By running command python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file cert.crt my own-made sertificate was created. I imported this certificate to Trusted Chrome sertificates but safe connection doesn't establish. When i pass https://example.com:8000/account/login/ I hit an error NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID,
Failed to confirm that this is the server example.com. Its safety certificate refers to *. The server may be configured incorrectly or someone is trying to intercept your data.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You either need a certificate that actually matches the host name you are using, or you need to tell Chrome you want to proceed despite this error.

Comment: Or use a service like https://ngrok.com to provide a secure tunnel to your local system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem(my custom local domain name was "mysite.com").

for me it was working correctly and when i ran `python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file cert.crt` suddenly mysite.com didn't point to 127.0.0.1 and i thought the problem is with runserver_plus but it was working correctly with https://127.0.0.1:8000 and https://localhost:8000 i checked it without ssl and i ran `python manage.py runserver` and mysite.com:8000 also didn't work(which was opening django pages some minutes earlier).

### problems

- The first problem is maybe about windows which is caching name resolution data [read here](https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot).
- the second problem is maybe about that you are using vpn or any proxy on your windows which will mess up with hosts local custom domain.

### solution

- I restarted my pc after that it took affected and mysite.com pointed to django at 127.0.0.1:8000. :)
- turn off your proxy or vpn. :)